# How to send SMS to multiple people in objective c using Twilio?

Tags: objective-c, sms, twilio

I can send sms to one person using following code with twilio api in iOS.

```
NSString *kTwilioSID = TWILIO_SID;
NSString *kTwilioSecret = TWILIO_SECRET;
NSString *kFromNumber = TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER;
NSString *kToNumber = TO_NUMBER;
NSString *kMessage = TWILIO_MESSAGE_HEADER;

NSString *urlString = [NSString
                       stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%@/SMS/Messages/",
                       kTwilioSID, kTwilioSecret,kTwilioSID];

NSDictionary*
dic = @{@"From":kFromNumber,@"To":kToNumber,@"Body":kMessage};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/xml"];
[manager POST:urlString parameters:dic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {       
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
 }];
```

Then I want to send sms to multiple people.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to embed your API secret (`kTwilioSecret`) in a client application, because unless you implement [SSL certificate pinning](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning), an attacker [routing their device to a proxy](https://www.raywenderlich.com/154244/charles-proxy-tutorial-ios) could easily obtain your API credentials (including the secret) and send messages with your account.

This is why their iOS client SDK does not support sending SMS. Your app should talk to your backend (where your API secret is safe), which should handle the logic for allowing the SMS's to be sent and then sending them through Twilio.

Make sure you are aware that Twilio uses [Rate-Limiting](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages#rate-limiting), so you can't send many messages at once from the same number. Short codes are subject to different rules though, but they are more expensive.

Now what you can do is implement some routine that manages rate limiting by only sending as many messages as Twilio allows you to in a given period of time, and/or using many numbers at once, on your backend.
(Or from iOS but I would discourage going with that, for the security issues mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Arthur, you're absolutely right about the security issues. We published a blog post on [how to send SMS messages from iOS using Swift](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html) and I'm sure it mostly applies to Objective C too.